# How to get an average of all of the first position digits of a large amount of numbers

Tags: python, numbers

My apologies, I'm not a coder but am trying to learn.

My immediate need though is for a project where we're using Python and what I need to do is get a script that will average all of the first place numbers in a large set of numbers. For example if the numbers were 101, 503, 695, 1002, 496 - I would need to average 1,3,5,2,6. Would someone be so kind as to show me how this can be done?

Comment: please ask relevant questions (specific not too general). Join  any group first to learn python.

Comment: relevant, specific questions? i'm pretty sure what i asked had both...

Comment: What part of the assignment do you not know how to do?

Comment: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#urgent

Comment: I don't know how to have python just average the first digit of a bunch of large strings of numbers.

Comment: Which part of that is giving your trouble, "python", "average", "first digit", or "large strings of numbers"?

Comment: Dmitry got it. He's a smart guy.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = [101, 503, 695, 1002, 496]
new_numbers = [int(str(x)[-1]) for x in numbers]

print(new_numbers)
```

Comment: Dmitry thank you very much! I would up your vote but I cannot. And thank you for understanding and not responding with snark and downvotes. You are a gentleman sir. No worries everyone else, I will not be back.